# How do I get my call log to stop listing my text messages

Tags: settings, samsung-galaxy-s-4, calls

I have a Galaxy S4 Mini. The call log on my Galaxy S4 Mini includes my text messages. I have to sort through dozens of text messages for every call that it lists. How can I set it to display only the calls?

Answer (score 2):

Open your phone application and go to `Recent > Settings > View By` and set it to what you require.

However, there is an issue on certain Samsung devices that once you press the back button, this setting is lost. It will also often be lost on reboot. If you are affected by this, then change the setting and just press the home button. It will remain like this until you reboot. If you are not affected then it's a one time thing.

Alternatively you could download a different dialer / call log application and just use that. Samsung's own one is quite slow I find.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this! I noticed that the setting gets lost sometimes, and sometimes it holds, but didn't investigate more. You are right, if I press "Home" it is kept, if I press "Back", the setting is lost. And this annoyance is still not fixed, also in Galaxy S4.